# OLAP skip level hierarchy

Tags: sql-server, ssas, olap

I have cube:

[image: cube]

and dimention HealthRecord with attributes AppointmentID, CourseID, PatientID. I set NullProcessing = Preserve for CourseID and AppointmentID attributes.

I add Patient, Course for him and Appointment in that course. I add HealthRecords with some HrItems to that appointment. Cube processing goes fine after that.

Then I add HealthRecord (with HrItem) directly to the Course:

```
INSERT INTO [HealthRecord] ([Id],[PatientID],[CourseID],[AppointmentID]) VALUES (N'61a69de5-75c0-4b48-8ef2-a3ff00f1c0f4',NULL,NULL,N'db5d256d-db9d-4342-829f-a3ff00f1b3dd');
INSERT INTO [HealthRecord] ([Id],[PatientID],[CourseID],[AppointmentID]) VALUES (N'7ba7c847-f996-49cb-88e8-a3ff00f1d54e',NULL,N'087ad199-260d-43cc-8dd7-a3ff00f1a09e',NULL);

INSERT INTO [HrItem] ([Id],[WordID],[HealthRecordID]) VALUES (N'18e7b735-7170-4641-a54c-a3ff00f1c0f4',N'00000043-0000-0000-0001-000000000043',N'61a69de5-75c0-4b48-8ef2-a3ff00f1c0f4');
INSERT INTO [HrItem] ([Id],[WordID],[HealthRecordID]) VALUES (N'cc841113-acb3-47cd-8faf-a3ff00f1e6c9',N'00000096-0000-0000-0001-000000000096',N'7ba7c847-f996-49cb-88e8-a3ff00f1d54e');
```

And there is error:
The attribute key cannot be found when processing: Table: `'dbo_HrItem'`, Column: `'HealthRecordID'`, Value: `'{7ba7c847-f996-49cb-88e8-a3ff00f1d54e}'`. The attribute is `'Id'`.

How to deal with that?

Comment: You need to add more information about exactly what command you are using (in what programming language) to add the HealthRecord

Comment: Simple SQL. Do not think that's the problem.

Comment: I believe that error is telling you that it cannot find the dimension attribute in the HealthRecord table that corresponds to the one in the HR_Item table with the value '{7ba7c847-f996-49cb-88e8-a3ff00f1d54e}'. Can you check both tables and ensure it exists?

Comment: Sure, they all at right place